# Wiring SMD Micro USB to ESP32 MCU

Tags: usb, uart, esp32

I am trying to connect a SMD micro USB to my ESP chip using a USB to UART bridge.  The schematic being followed is attached below.  But there are a few things on the diagram that I find confusing, the bridge chip shows several I/Os connected that are not labeled anywhere else in the diagram.  The second attached picture shows the connections I am unsure about.  Does anyone know what these I/Os might correspond to?

Unlike the diagram, I am using CP2102N-A02-GQFN28R for USB to UART Bridge.  I believe I/Os are identical though. [bridge datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/cp2102n_datasheet-1634912.pdf)

Lastly, I am not sure what is being accomplished in the third attached picture.  I understand how to wire this, but what is the purpose?

[image: ESP Wiring]
[image: Bridge]
[image: transistors]

Comment: Those i/o are probably not used and labelled for convenience. The two transistor circuit? The truth table explains what they do. In a nutshell it is for activating the bootloader in order to download new code. It ensures only a specific sequence on the dtr and rts signals will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these USB to UART devices has ability to operate a variety of features for RS232 systems. They are used to send signals or receive signals back from devices for proper operation.

You wont need them if you are using it to program a ESP32 module. For that, you will only need RX(Receive Data), TX(Transmit Data), RTS(Request to Send), DTR(Data Terminal Ready), D+ and D-.

Answering your second question, that is to put the device in Flash mode. IO0 and RST pin of the ESPs need to be in a specific state for that operation. When you press the Upload button in our IDE, the IDE will send a command though D+ and D- which will tell the UART device to send signals to the MOSFETs in that schema. This will set RST and IO0 to LOW and they will be set back to HIGH in a synchronized manner. This is to enable the device to go in flash mode without the need to the user to press any button.